React NextUI Navbar: Icons not displaying in mobile view, showing "open navigation menu" and "close navigation menu" text instead
I'm currently learning how to create responsive navbars using React, and I'm using the NextUI library for this. I followed the NextUI Navbar documentation and copied the code from the "With Menu" section exactly as given to test it out.
Everything works fine in the desktop view, but when I switch to the mobile view, the menu bar and close icons are not visible. Instead, there is text saying "open navigation menu" and "close navigation menu". I can't figure out why.
Here is the code I used from the website:
import React from "react";
import {Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarContent, NavbarItem, NavbarMenuToggle, NavbarMenu, NavbarMenuItem, Link, Button} from "@nextui-org/react";
import {AcmeLogo} from "./AcmeLogo.jsx";

export default function App() {
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const menuItems = [
    "Profile",
    "Dashboard",
    "Activity",
    "Analytics",
    "System",
    "Deployments",
    "My Settings",
    "Team Settings",
    "Help & Feedback",
    "Log Out",
  ];

  return (
    <Navbar onMenuOpenChange={setIsMenuOpen}>
      <NavbarContent>
        <NavbarMenuToggle
          aria-label={isMenuOpen ? "Close menu" : "Open menu"}
          className="sm:hidden"
        />
        <NavbarBrand>
          <AcmeLogo />
          <p className="font-bold text-inherit">ACME</p>
        </NavbarBrand>
      </NavbarContent>

      <NavbarContent className="hidden sm:flex gap-4" justify="center">
        <NavbarItem>
          <Link color="foreground" href="#">
            Features
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem isActive>
          <Link href="#" aria-current="page">
            Customers
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem>
          <Link color="foreground" href="#">
            Integrations
          </Link>
        </NavbarItem>
      </NavbarContent>
      <NavbarContent justify="end">
        <NavbarItem className="hidden lg:flex">
          <Link href="#">Login</Link>
        </NavbarItem>
        <NavbarItem>
          <Button as={Link} color="primary" href="#" variant="flat">
            Sign Up
          </Button>
        </NavbarItem>
      </NavbarContent>
      <NavbarMenu>
        {menuItems.map((item, index) => (
          <NavbarMenuItem key={`${item}-${index}`}>
            <Link
              color={
                index === 2 ? "primary" : index === menuItems.length - 1 ? "danger" : "foreground"
              }
              className="w-full"
              href="#"
              size="lg"
            >
              {item}
            </Link>
          </NavbarMenuItem>
        ))}
      </NavbarMenu>
    </Navbar>
  );
}

I tried importing and using React icons, but there was no change. I ensured that all necessary dependencies were installed and the error still remains. How to rectify this?

Just saw this as I was having the same issue, this solved it for me.
Have you added the path to node modules in the tailwind config file?
"./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",

So the content section would look like...
content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./node_modules/@nextui-org/theme/dist/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
